# Can visualvm send automatic email notification

Tags: monitoring, visualvm, jvisualvm, java-server, server-monitoring

We are having an web application hosted on Tomcat 6x and would like to set-up a server health monitoring tool like ***visualvm which could send us 'Automatic email notifications' incase of any issues with memory or other aspects***. Since we are planning ot use visualvm that comes along with JDK (1.6 in our environment),

could anyone help us to know if there is way to configure automatic email notification ?

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, but this feature is currently not available.